# How to configure WordPress to create thumbnails

Tags: uploads, media-library

I was having a problem on a 3.8.0 install where thumbnails were not being created by WordPress.

I thought it was the install, so I installed 3.9.2, not upgrade, but completely different install.

And now it is having the same issue. It will let me upload images, but when I save them, no thumbnails are created.

I have *'Crop thumbnail to exact dimensions (normally thumbnails are proportional)'* set **checked** as well as *'Organize my uploads into month- and year-based folders'*.

Is there some other place I need to activate or configure to get Media Manager to create thumbnails when I upload a new image?

Comment: For a nice primary debugging, would you please confirm us that your `WP_DEBUG` is set true, and all the plugins are deactivated and you are using a default theme like TwentyThirteen etc. and the same thing is happening?

Comment: Thanks. Can the WP_DEBUG be set without writing some script? The 3.9.2 is 100% fresh and only has my one plugin on it. ANd it is using the default TwentyThirteen theme. On my local server, everything is working fine. So I am pretty sure my plugin is not causing the issue.

Comment: Please deactivate your *that* single plugin too and open the `wp-config.php` and set the `WP_DEBUG` to `true` so that we can solely blame WordPress - I hope you get the debugging process.

Comment: Thanks Mayeenul. Still nothing. No errors, and no thumbnails. I even went in and changed the folder permissions from 755 to 777 and still nothing. Is it possible my server needs something that Wordpress needs to make thumbnails?

Comment: Can you indicate how you're testing for the creation of thumbnails, as well as how you're trying to use them in your code? Are you aware both 3.9.2 and 3.8.0 are several major versions out of date? The current latest version is 4.1, and any solution will assume you're using the latest version.

Comment: As a sidenote, if it's the chmod, the required chmod will depend on your hosts, we can't help with hosting issues here as they're too localised

Comment: Also can you confirm that your server has the necessary PHP extensions to manipulate/resize/crop images? E.g. GD or Imagemagick?

Comment: 1: I am stuck with 3.9.2. 2: changed permissions to 777 3: I am not sure what extensions are needed for this. I tried to find that information but never found it. Thanks everyone for your responses.